# Azure Data Factory Data Flow 'Invalid Pseudocolumn'

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a data flow where i added an integer parameter, pMovType. In the dataflow source i try go get at it, but cannot. When I try to use it in $pMovType form it just gives 'Invalid Pseudocolumn'.

How does one get at a parameter value inside the query of a source in a data flow?

I have tried to hunt around for a solution, but everything people suggest seems to fail, like {$pMovType}, @pMovType, @{pMovType}, {@pMovType}, and a few others.

I have dumbed my query down to

select $pMovType as teste

And still get the same. Is this not the way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above error arises due to incorrect usage of the parameter in the query.

To get the desired output, you need to use **string interpolation in the query dynamic expression**.

Use the below dynamic expression in the query dynamic editor.

```
"select {$pMovType} as number"
```

Here, click on **Open expression builder** and give the above expression.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]